# How do they shoot Dual-Roles where camera is moving or both characters interact?

Tags: film-techniques, production

I was wondering how they shoot dual-roles in movies and after searching found an [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13356/how-are-dual-role-films-shot); I knew some of this before, but I have seen movies where:

- The Camera is moving.
- The actor is shaking hands or interacting the other double (the same actor).

The recently released [Dhoom 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAE&url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1833673/&ei=kfrGUobVMobhyQGC5oDYCw&usg=AFQjCNETomcC9BNDHdLX-rPSrjqhNHAI5A&sig2=CaGOvRMKq-Zf0OsK7Bf2Hw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) and [Krrish 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAE&url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1029231/&ei=rfrGUrjAEYa6yQH39oHoDw&usg=AFQjCNEt42hQ5b-einQg9iFIhyvhmA1oZg&sig2=NqBgr6plYcaJeP9KXJeW1g&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) are good examples where [Aamir Khan](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQFjAF&url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0451148/&ei=UPrGUsGPOITwyQGfvYDIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGVfekjBbm8tx4u6IkWYMta60KbRw&sig2=71-H5PE2ntKYu4LPydyZBw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) hugs his twin whilst the camera is moving. Similarly, [Hrithik Roshan](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAE&url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004335/&ei=K_rGUunAG-6GyQHWhYDYCw&usg=AFQjCNHYOvfQfTArt9Qe5rnQscg_LZN8vA&sig2=yUrvU0g_NpKCUXAcW2z9AA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) and his father (double) do the same.

Is there any **Behind the scenes** of this type of shot? Any explanations as to how this is achieved?

Comment: Green screen, shot for one character with green screen then the other character. Then merge both.

Comment: One actor hugging the other?
How do they make this?

Comment: Body double can also be used for hugging scenes, first by using body double for 1st character, then for second and then mixing both together. Didn't have any demonstrate video yet, will add it if got any.

Comment: Didn't got the Behind the scene video but got Aamirs interview on it, see the answer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How are dual-role films shot?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13356/how-are-dual-role-films-shot)

Answer (score 8):

Here are Aamir's words on the double role of Dhoom 3 -

> **Q:** The double role in Dhoom 3 is different from what we are used to
>   seeing, as there are many close-up shots and movements involving both
>   Sahir and Samar in the same frame. How was the execution process for
>   you as an actor?
>
> **Aamir:** With newer technology it becomes difficult for the actor, as the kind
>   of shots you can design for a double role are limitless. Earlier due
>   to constraints of technology, you could not touch each other in a
>   double role. Physical contact could not be captured, as you would end
>   up touching yourself on screen. The camera used to be pretty-much
>   static and in wide. Here were are hugging each other, exchanging hats,
>   one is giving an Apple to the other…Because with motion control
>   cameras, you can duplicate the same moment a number of times. The
>   angle and position are all locked in a computer, so a situation can be
>   recreated identically, multiple times, for an actor to perform
>   different shots for his respective character in a double role.
>
> For example take the shot in which Samar is getting ready in front of
>   a mirror! Sahir is talking to Samar’s reflection in the mirror and
>   asks him about where he is going. Once he names Aliya (Katrina Kaif’s
>   character) and confesses his love, Sahir comes face-to-face and covers
>   the mirror to confront Samar. Later Sahir once-again uncovers the
>   mirror and tells Samar that Aliya is actually coming for him.

Full article at [indiatimes.com](http://www.indiatimes.com/entertainment/bollywood/aamir-khan-reveals-his-top-dhoom-3-moments-120797.html).

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a [body double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_double) of similar build and appearance to the actor. The similarity can be enhanced by use of makeup and prosthetic and careful cutting and composition of shots may be enough to preserve the illusion. For example showing a closeup composite shot when they are physically separate and then cutting to a shot where one actor's face is partially obscured for the interaction. For example in a hug it is often difficult to see both people's faces clearly from any angle even without careful shot composition.

Modern digital technology also makes this easier as it is now entirely possible to 'paste' one actors face onto another of reasonably similar appearance. This technique was used for the scene where Lena Headey appeared to walk naked through the streets on Game of Thrones. It is her face digitally composited onto a body double.

As mentioned digital technology also makes it reasonably easy to accurately replicate camera moves over an over again and advanced in processing power mean that composite shots can be processed quickly enough to be checked, at least in rough form on set so precise positioning and movements of actors can be refined on the fly and small discrepancies can be digitally massaged later.

Similarly careful rehearsing and aids such as marks on the floor, simple puppets and other reference points are more traditional ways to help and actor to get their movements precise enough to match up to another performance compposited in.

Motion capture can be used to allow digital doubles to be accurately matched to the movements of stand-ins. For example in Lord of the Rings a lot of the shots with Gollum are [rotoscoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping) over Any Serkiss's real-time performance with the live actors rather than having them interact with empty space.

Similar techniques may be used when a stunt performer is used to double for an actor.

Answer (score -5):

That can be done through Chroma technique as usual and cloning technique without chroma . 
Check this out , 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp8j0BXq250&HD=1

Comment: This is not much of an answer and I can't help but suspect you or one of your friends posted this clip. It has nothing to do with complicated physical interaction like hugging, shaking hands, etc.